# Center align divs vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have following code

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one"> </div>
    <div id="two"> </div>
    <div id="three"> </div>
    <div id="four"> </div>
</div>
```

I need to align the middle 4 div as below, keeping equal space at each side (top-space = bottom-space and right-space = left-space):

```
______________________________________
|                                    |
|         ________  ________         |
|        |        ||        |        |
|        |  one   ||   two  |        |
|        |        ||        |        |
|        |________||________|        |
|         ________  ________         |
|        |        ||        |        |
|        | three  ||  four  |        |
|        |        ||        |        |
|        |________||________|        |
|                                    |
|____________________________________|
```

Four div's equally spaced, please can anyone me help me out here with any css snippet? Also I do see a lot of question over this, but can't get this fixed. Can someone point me to any useful link that explains all the concepts related to the div alignment perfectly ?

(Folks, I know this would be a duplicate, but please help as I am just going round and round by googling.)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way that works in all modern browsers, including IE8: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6p2Tf/)**.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div><br />
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border:1px solid #999;
}
#main {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
#one,#two,#three,#four{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;   
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

​
Note that i did have to add one break tag (`<br />`) to your code.

Comment: this doesn't display center in any browser i tested: Safari, Chrome, FireFox or iPhone. it aligns to the top left corner. @mtk, this is not your solution

Comment: @j08691 Does `IE8` count as a modern browser?

Answer (score 1):

@j08691 Has a good example. But here's mine if it's of any use...

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">

    <div>
        <div style="width: 480px; float: left;">
            <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #F00;">
                1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 480px; float: left;">
            <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #F00;">
                2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div style="width: 480px; float: left;">
            <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #F00;">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 480px; float: left;">
            <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #F00;">
                4
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Centering horizontally is the easy part, but there is a neat trick to get things aligned vertically using absolute positioning and negative margins. [**Here's a working example I wrote a few years back**](http://www.mackie.com/products/hrmk2series/cutaway/diagram.html).

Here's some code and explanation:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  /* gets the first pixel in the center of the browser */  
    left: 50%;
    height: 860px;
    width: 860px;
    margin-top: -430px; /* negative margin half the height of the div to make it appear center */  
    margin-left: -430px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    overflow: visible; /* allows an absolutely positioned element to contain floats */ 
    }
#one, #two, #three, #four { 
    float: left;
    height: 400px; 
    width: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 20px; 
    }
#one, #three { 
     margin-right: 0; 
     }
#one, #two {  
    margin-top: 20px;  
    margin-bottom: 0;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I went for a slightly different answer (but @j08691 has a good solution),

```
#main{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;

    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
}

#one, #two, #three, four{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Complete working code that I tested it on was,

```
    <html>
<head>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

#main{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;

    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
}

#one, #two, #three, four{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.box{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}


#one{
    background-color:#f00;
}
#two{
    background-color:#0f0;
}
#three{
    background-color:#00f;
}
#four{
    background-color:#000;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="one" class="box"> </div>
    <div id="two" class="box"> </div>
    <div id="three" class="box"> </div>
    <div id="four"class="box" > </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```