# Vertically aligning repeating DIVs generated by PHP script, two per line

Tags: css, html, css-float, vertical-alignment, repeat

I have a script which generates a DIV for each message written on a donation wall on my site.  You can see the donation wall [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/donate/#donorwall).

This is the section of the script that generates the DIVs:

```
foreach( $donors as $donor ):
$output = '<div class="donorbox"><p><strong>'.$donor->name.'</strong> donated '.$donation.'<small class="date time">on '.$datetime.'</small><blockquote class="comment">'.nl2br($donor->comment).'</blockquote></p></div>';
endforeach;
```

I have set the width of each donorbox DIV to 43.5%, and added float:left, so that 2 always fit on each line.

Because the DIVs are going to have different heights, depending on how long the message the user writes, the display of the divs is rather uneven (see page linked to above).  So I would like to find a way of centering the DIVs vertically so that there are always two per line, but so that they display more evenly, i.e. so that the vertical center point of the 2 DIVs is aligned.

Another problem with the current implementation is that when the height of a DIV on the left is greater than the height of the div on the right, the next div stays on the right side of the page, rather than being forced to the left side, and this is not what I want.  You can see this now if you look at the page and reduce the width of your browser window.  The third donorbox DIV stays on the right.

To hopefully make what I am on about clearer I include two images below:

**CURRENT**

[image]

**REQUIRED**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could give us an image to show us what you mean. Sometimes I find images easier to explain things with. This article may be of use: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html. Also, check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090406/center-align-divs-vertically-and-horizontally. You may want to float your divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure about the height of the element always use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`. If you change it now - they will always be positioned correctly. In order for them to be vertically centered - simply add `vertical-align: middle` to them as well :)

P.s. If you need IE7 support for `display: inline-block;` add `*display: inline; *zoom:1;` ;)

Comment: Is there a way of positioning the right blocks relative to the right of the content area, as I am having difficultly setting variable widths/margins for the divs such that they are spaced evenly and always fit 2 across the page.

Comment: in other words - you need the left one to be touching the left side of the container and the right one - the right side? And if the `width` is small - the right one should be sticking to the right? Do I understand you correctly? Because I don't understand why you have a variable width on these blocks

Comment: I have a variable width because the whole site is variable width - I would like the blocks to fill the available space in the #donorwall div with  evenly sized spaces between the edges of the container and the edges of the blocks and between the blocks, e.g. left-edge|2% space|left-block|2% space|right-block|2% space|left-edge, with the blocks taking up the remaining space. I am trying to get the total width to add up to 100%, so in this case I would be setting the width of each block to  47%.  However this isn't working for all widths, presumably because of the conversion to pixels.

Comment: Hm, that's tricky :) I think the `text-align: justify` technique may be of some help... it will always position the right block to the right increasing the distance between the blocks if needed (my advice will be to test the `width` on the lowest resolution you need) the way `justify` works may be seen here: - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/xbmkr/  . In this fiddle the width is set to 40%

Comment: I updated the fiddle to add the `width` in percentage. You can see it here - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/xbmkr/1/  Hope that helps. Try resizing the Result window to see it in action

Comment: That looks good.  I will have a go at implementing it later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can let the second one float right by using something like:

```
.yourclass:nth-of-type(2n) {float:right !important;}
```

Comment: Mmmh, except that the vertical-align no longer works.  Is there a way of preserving this?

Comment: this is because `vertical-align` doesn't work with `block` elements. And `floats` are rendered block-level even if you state `display: whatever_you_put_here_will_not_be_applied`

Comment: I think you need to create a container for every post div that has a fixed height. Like <div class="container"><div class="content"></div> </div> Then you would need to set the .container css to position:relative; and the .content css position:absolute; To align the to align the inner .content to the center use top:50%; Use margin property to correct the offset we do that by margin-top = - 0.5 x height. Since your elements height varies you will need to use something like $('.content').height(); to get the elements height then use .css to adept its margin-top to the  - 0.5 x "element hight".